# getView give wrong position for item

Tags: android

this is getView for my adapter, it gives wrong position for each item! so i can't access to my item detail. please help me about this problem, i really confused :-(

```
public class adapter_common extends ArrayAdapter<item> {
private final Context context;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
        Rowposition = position;
        username.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        message_content.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getDes());
        like_count.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getLike() + " لایک");
        //row_pos.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getRow_pos());
        final String Like = itemsArrayList.get(position).getLike();
        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        });
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        btn_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

public adapter_common(Context context, ArrayList<item> itemsArrayList) {

    super(context, R.layout.post, itemsArrayList);
    context = context;
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your entire class.  Cant assume your logic.

Comment: username & message_content & like_count are just being replaced everytime, your not taking them from the inflated view the android systems giving you , why ? whats the point of a list then ?

Comment: hey j2emanue , now item is correctly set into the adapter, but each row has wrong position!

Comment: how is your list evening scrolling ? your rootview is always empty. your better off showing how your initializing username and message_content.  By the way calling new operator in getview can be scary.

Comment: thank you, my problem is solved , i change position to final position and solved !

Answer (score 0):

Exemple from my application from the method getView

```
public SaldoProdutos getItem(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position);
    return null;
}

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    v = null;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saldo_list_item, null);
    }

    SaldoProdutos  produtos = itemList.get(position);
    TextView Produtos  =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProdutoSaldo);
    Produtos.setText(""+produtos.descricao);
    TextView Pontos = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.PontosSaldo);
    Pontos.setText("" + produtos.pontos + " Pontos");
    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    int color1 = generator.getRandomColor();
    String inicial = (String) Produtos.getText();
    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(inicial.substring(0,1), color1 );
    ImageView imagem  = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iconecliente);
    imagem.setImageDrawable(drawable);

     if (mSelectedItemsIds.get(position))
     {


         ImageView check = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.check);
         v.setBackgroundColor(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
         TextDrawable drawable1 = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(" ", 0xff616161);
         imagem.setImageDrawable(drawable1);
         check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

    else {




         ImageView check = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.check);
         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
         String inicial1 = (String) Produtos.getText();
         TextDrawable drawable1 = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(inicial1.substring(0, 1), color1);
         ImageView imagem1 = (ImageView)    v.findViewById(R.id.iconecliente);
         imagem1.setImageDrawable(drawable1);
         check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }



    return v;

}
```

in your activity or fragment you do adapter.getItem(position)

Answer (score 0):

are using `Rowposition` varaible to navigate into the details?

I guess this is a global variable which holds the last called value of 'position' and almost returns wrong index on using it. Instead make `position` variable as final and use it in clickListeners.

regards,
 sha